# button into tooltip using qtip plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote this code below used qtip plugin for html link :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#login').qtip({
            content: '<table><tr><td>Username</td><td><INPUT type="text" value=""   name="username" title="Enter Username" class="txtbx"/></td>' +
            '<td>Password</td><td><INPUT type="password" value="" name="password" title="Enter password" class="txtbx"/></td>' +
            '<td><button id="loginbtn" type="submit" >login</button></td></tr></table>',
            show: { when: { event: 'click' },
                effect: { type: 'fade', length: 200 }
            },
            hide: { when: { event: 'unfocus' },
                effect: { type: 'fade', length: 430 }
            },
            position: {
            adjust: { resize: true 

        },
                corner: {
                    target: 'bottomLeft',
                    tooltip: 'topLeft'
                }
            },
            style: {
                name: 'dark',
                width: { max: 700 }
            }
        });
     });
```

but the submit button doesn't work !!!!??? any help here !!

Comment: How do you define "work"? Is an ajax request to be submitted? Is there an event that runs when a user clicks on the button? Is a form supposed to be submitted?

Answer (score 1):

Does replacing `<button id="loginbtn" type="submit" >login</button>` with

```
<input name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn" type="submit" value="login" />
```

work?

Also, I don't see a [form element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) anywhere with an action or method attribute wrapping all of your form inputs. Hence, I don't think the browser knows what to do when you submit the form.

Comment: yes ur right about form element !! so what do u recommend for that?

Comment: as the link says, it depends on what you aim to do. the action attribute takes an address to a server side script to be run. the method attribute notes what type of request is made. i would read up on form elements and server side scripting.

Comment: acually i am start working on design didn't write server side code yet
but check up this link for complete code 
http://aspspider.info/termi/

Comment: I think its better if i put login controls into div and hide/show it as i want , its much better that using tooltip ?